# Using interface function defined in DLL

Tags: vb.net, interface

I'm using an interface defined in a DLL.

[image]

When I call...

```
    m.GetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(btVol)
```

... I get a Null Reference Exception because "m" is nothing.

However, I can't use "new" on this interface.

How would I use this interface correctly?

I did read on implements, but I didn't find an example similar to this interface.

Thank you.

Edit: I know now that I need to type

```
 Implements Vannatech.CoreAudio.Interfaces.IAudioEndpointVolume
```

and the functions will automatically be added to my class.

However, I'm not sure what to do with the NonImplementedException for example here:

```
Public Function GetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(ByRef level As Single) As Integer Implements IAudioEndpointVolume.GetMasterVolumeLevelScalar
    Throw New NotImplementedException()
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: You need to implement it..

Comment: Firstly, don't post pictures of code.  Code is text, as are error message.  Post text and explain where and under what circumstances the error occurs.  We can't copy and paste pictures to test or search on.  Someone with 1600 rep points shouldn't need to be told that.  Screenshots can be an adjunct to posted code but not a replace for it.

Comment: **EVERY** example is similar.  Interfaces only define what functionality a type that implements it will have.  It doesn't provide any of that functionality.  You have to define a class that implements that interface and then provide an implementation for every member that the interface includes.  **EVERY** example will do that, so **EVERY** example is similar.

Comment: @jmcilhinney After I typed "Implements Vanna...", all functions were automatically added. For example "    Public Function SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(level As Single, eventContext As Guid) As Integer Implements IAudioEndpointVolume.SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Function" What would I do with that? Do I simply need to return 1 or do something else?

Comment: Sorry for the screenshot. When I copy the code, the nodes get expanded, and it would be a terribly long bunch of code to show here.

Comment: Then edit it. Screenshots make it much harder for us to help you.

Comment: As you've seen, when you declare a class and then specify that it implements an interface, the IDE will add all the members of that interface to your class.  That is enough for your class to be used wherever a instance of that interface is required but your class still won't do anything.  Any time a member of the interface is called on an instance of your class, a `NotImplementedException` will be thrown because you have declared that member but you have to provided an implementation for it.  You need to provide that implementation, i.e. write code that does what you want to do.

Comment: *"Do I simply need to return 1 or do something else?"*.  What use would that be? You are missing something fundamental here. Just having a method named `SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar` doesn't mean that anything will happen. You have to actually write code inside that method to set the master volume. The interface does say "this is what I do".  It says "this is what you have to do". If you expect something to happen then you have to make it happen.

Comment: You might want to [read this](https://blog.sverrirs.com/2016/02/windows-coreaudio-api-in-c.html). He appears to be using the same library that you are, although the link on that page goes to the old CodePlex page rather than GitHub.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I'm still unsure what I should do. In that stub, how could I access that function defined in that interface? I just don't see a way.

Comment: The `MMDeviceEnumerator` class that he's using in that code appears to be from [here](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/NAudio/CoreAudioApi/MMDeviceEnumerator.cs).  You then need to do the same sort of thing that he's doing with it.  This question has gone beyond what you asked in the first place. You asked the question as though it was a simple case of implementing an interface yourself, which this is not.  You need to spend a bit more time studying that code and then, if needed, ask a more specific question. You might start by just using that linked code as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it:

I simply need to type

```
Implements Vannatech.CoreAudio.Interfaces.IAudioEndpointVolume
```

By doing that, all functions will automatically be added to the class in which I typed this.

I just didn't scroll down enough to see that.